# Do I have to buy a Disney world dining plan for the whole stay?

Tags: usa, food-and-drink, disney

I have a question about the dining plan (quick service) in Disney world located in Orlando.

I want to stay in a Hotel in Disney for 20 days, but I only want buy the dining plan for 15 days.

So can I buy the dining plan for 15 days and use it across 20 days? I’d like to do this because I have some lunches outside Disney; so the dining plan for 20 days will have meals that I won't use.

Answer (score 17):

I couldn't find the information on the official website, however I found a [blog post specifying all the rules](http://www.disneyfoodblog.com/disney-dining-plan-faq/) on the dining plans. Specifically it says on dining plans:

> **Can I get the Dining Plan for more or fewer days than my hotel stay?**
>
> No. The Dining Plan can only be arranged for the exact number of
>   NIGHTS of your hotel package. The only way around this would be to
>   split your reservation. For example, if you’ll be staying at a WDW
>   hotel for five nights, but only want the Dining Plan for three nights
>   (because, say, you’re going to visit Universal Studios and Sea World),
>   you could make two different room/package reservations. One for three
>   nights and one for two. However, be aware that your Dining Plan
>   credits would only be valid for the package part of your stay. This
>   means that you would only be able to use the credits on the first
>   three consecutive days of your trip.

So it seems that you can use the credits freely within the period you have the dining plan for (you could use 3 meals on one day and only 1 the next day), but you can't use the credits for longer than the duration of the plan.

Comment: Can I buy additional credits if I need more?

Answer (score 7):

> So can I buy the dining plan for 15 days and use it across 20 days?

No.  The Disney Dining Plan is a lengh-of-stay option so unless you split your reservation, on or off property, you will get 20 night of credits.

But, it's still pretty easy to use them.  If you have breakfast at your resort every day, that's half the credits right there.  Or use a Snack Credit for a to-go item you can take to the other parks.

Then on non-Disney days, use one for lunch and dinner as well.

Also, keep in mind that you can use convert 1 Quick Service Credit to three Snack Credits which are often usable at the Epcot festival booths.  It's very easy to burn through credits at Food & Wine or Flower & Garden.

Comment: The last time I went to Disney and buy the Dinning plan, I have the problem you are describing with the credits and I didn’t know until now what exactly happened. So thank for that information too!